# How to turn off breaking line in VSC extension Prettier

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

how can I change this breaking HTML tags in the Prettier extension for VSC?

```html
<div 
v-for="(task, index) in todos" 
:key="task.id" 
class="task-list">
    <input 
    v-model="task.completed" 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="" 
    id="" />
    <div>
        <div 
        v-if="!task.editing" 
        @dblclick="changeTitle(task)" 
        class="task"       
        v-bind:class="{ completedTask: task.completed }">
            {{ task.title }}
        </div>
        <input 
        v-else type="text" 
        v-model="task.title" 
        @blur="doneEdit(task)" 
        @keyup.enter="doneEdit(task)"
        @keyup.esc="cancelEditing(task)" v-focus />
```

And change this to format like this ? Is a way to change this settings in vue and html file ?

```html
<div v-for="(task, index) in todos" :key="task.id" class="task-list">
    <input v-model="task.completed" type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
    <div>
        <div v-if="!task.editing" @dblclick="changeTitle(task)" class="task"
            v-bind:class="{ completedTask: task.completed }">
            {{ task.title }}
        </div>
        <input v-else type="text" v-model="task.title" @blur="doneEdit(task)" @keyup.enter="doneEdit(task)"
            @keyup.esc="cancelEditing(task)" v-focus />
```

Comment: I believe you can set the print width to a higher value for the prettier. The default is 80 characters, so it breaks the long lines into smaller chunks.
https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width